# Change boolean data when adding new registration

Tags: python, django, django-models

In this piece of code l want to change the boolean data of room when adding new registration
For example: when l add new registration in django admin
the boolean data of room should change to False

```py
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

#This class Rooms for adding rooms
class Rooms(models.Model):
    room_num = models.IntegerField()
    room_bool = models.BooleanField(default=True) #if room_bool = True room is open, else closed.
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.room_num}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Room'

#This class Registration for visitors, to open room for the them
class Registration(models.Model):
    rooms = models.ForeignKey(Rooms, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pasport_serial_num = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
    img = models.FileField()
    visit_date = models.DateTimeField()
    leave_date = models.DateTimeField()
    guest_count = models.IntegerField()

    def func(self):
        room = Rooms.objects.filter(room_bool=True)
        for i in room:
            if i.room_num == int(self.rooms):
                i.room_bool = False #this should change when adding new registration
                i.save()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and ask a specific question. "Please can you help me" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). Start by *explaining the problem*; when you run the code, what happens? What is supposed to happen instead? How is that different? Also, please try to write in proper sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Django's signals for that. Just create `signals.py` in your app's folder and do that:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Registration


@receiver(post_save, sender=Registration)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.rooms.room_bool = False
        instance.rooms.save()
```

and add to your `apps.py` file in same app:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'your_app'

    def ready(self):
        import your_app.signals
```

That signal will change proper `Registration` related `Rooms` object's `room_bool` to `False` when it was saved during creation.

PS always name your model with singular version. Look how awfully looks `Rooms` when you actually talk about single room ;)

Comment: It's just bomb. thanks for your reply. Is it possible to make it so that ```leave_date``` (leaving time) so that when it comes automatically rooms_bool = True

Comment: ```def time(request,pk):
    date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    reg = Registration.objects.get(pk=pk)
    room = Rooms.objects.get(pk=pk)
    a = reg.leave_date.replace(tzinfo=None) >= datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=None)
    if a != True:
        reg.room_bool = True
        reg.save()
        room.room_bool = True
        room.save()``` this is my code for views.py and urls.py

Comment: For another question please ask another Question. Reading code in comments is tough and easy to be misunderstood.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72361530/when-a-certain-time-value-comes-from-false-back-to-true

Comment: and how to do so but when editing?
when I create it changes, but when I edit an existing one, nothing happens

Comment: @RyadovoyZadrot just delete `if created` part :)

Answer (score 0):

you can override the save method of the Registration class to be called every time a Registration object has been created or updated.

```
class Registration(models.Model):
...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.rooms.room_bool = False
            self.rooms.save()
            
        return super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

the if condition is for checking creation or updating.

`if self.pk` for the creation and else for updating the object.